# Remove a specific x value from ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to remove the points 4 and 5 from the x-axis of the plot I generated using ggplot. Currently my x-values only include 0, 1, 2, 3, and 6.

Here is the my.data data frame:

```
       x             y
1      2     0.1250000
2      0     0.3750000
3      0     0.3500000
4      0     0.6060606
5      1     0.7000000
6      0     0.6000000
7      0     0.4500000
8      6     0.9500000
9      0     0.7000000
10     3     0.5000000
11     0     0.6000000
12     3     0.1250000
13     0     0.3750000
14     0     0.3333333
15     1     0.6818182
16     0     0.0000000
17     2     0.5000000
```

Code:

```
ggplot(my.data, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()+geom_smooth()
```

Here is the plot that is generated:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me, what you want. Do you want to end the x-axis range at 3. Then (see solution by DatamineR), you can use `+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 3)`. Or do you want to have only the x-values that actually appear in your data on the x-axis. Then maybe using `ggplot(my.data, aes(factor(x),y))` is what you need.

Comment: Ah ok. Not sure why this got down-voted, guess the question wasn't specific enough.

Comment: Well, it still isn't clear enough. Please edit it and make it clearer. And it would also be good, if you could add some data. You could post the output of `dput(my.data)`.

Answer (score 1):

For example (using `mtcars`). This is *zooming in*, i.e. the stats are nor influenced by the reduction of the data:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,qsec)) + geom_point()+geom_smooth() + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(10, 25))
```